# Is there an inverse function of DayOfWeek::getDisplayName()

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date-parsing

I need a converter that converts `DayOfWeek` into `String` and the other way around given some `Locale` and `TextStyle`.
One way is straight forward:

```
public String getAsString(DayOfWeek day, TextStyle style, Locale locale){
    return day.getDisplayName(style, locale);
}
```

For the other way I did not find any useful methods in the `java.time` package. I'm looking for something like `LocalDate::parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)` but for `DayOfWeek`.

Comment: If your `DateTimeFormatter` has the day of week in its pattern, then parsing does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DayOfWeek` doesn't have a `parse` method, but you can build a `DateTimeFormatter` and use it with `DayOfWeek::from` to parse the `String`:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public DayOfWeek parseFromString(String str, TextStyle style, Locale locale) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        // Day of the week field, using the same TextStyle
        .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, style)
        // use the same locale
        .toFormatter(locale);
    // parse returns a TemporalAccessor, DayOfWeek::from converts it to a DayOfWeek object
    return formatter.parse(str, DayOfWeek::from);
}
```

With this, you can get the `DayOfWeek` from the `String` you created:

```
String dayOfWeekString = getAsString(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);
System.out.println(dayOfWeekString); // monday

DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = parseFromString(dayOfWeekString, TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek); // MONDAY (return of DayOfWeek.toString())
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`-API... looks quite powerful :-)

Comment: Indeed, it's a very powerful and useful class!

Comment: Very elegant and general.